# Qual è il significato di "saltare sul banco" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nella versione in italiano dell'episodio *La nascita del giullare* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> Doveti credermi... datemi ascolto! 
>          Non è nemmeno per caso che son **saltato sul banco** a farvi far sghignazzi... No, e nemmeno è successo che mia madre, guardandomi bambino spaparanzato nella culla che ridevo a sganascio, abbia esclamato: «Ma che bella faccina simpatica... Allegria mi fai!, pagliacciolino ridente! Guarda, da grande ti faccio fare il giullare!»

Non capisco cosa vuol dire l'espressione "saltare sul banco" in questo passaggio. Ho cercato il vocabolo "banco" su parecchi dizionari, ma nessuna delle accezioni che ho  trovato sembra avere senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "saltare sul banco" nel brano precedente?

Comment: Probabilmente un riferimento al sostantivo saltimbanco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Saltato sul banco" in questo caso significa proprio "messo a fare il saltimbanco" (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/saltimbanco/ ); 
il narratore in questo brano ripercorre le origini della sua "vocazione", ammettendo che non è stato un caso se abbia scelto la professione di "saltare sul banco" (a fare il buffone), ma che nemmeno questa sua attitudine si sia manifestata fin dalla più tenera età come fosse una predestinazione.